# Toad 8.6.0.38 SQL Editor won't allow editing

Tags: oracle-database, toad

I am using Toad for Oracle version 8.6.0.38.

I have found that recently the SQL editor refuses to let me edit anything. If I use the schema browser to generate a select statemnt to the clipboard and paste it in the editor, I can’t change it. I have to first paste it in some other text editor to edit it and then paste as is in the sql editor to run.

After a power trip caused my PC to shut down, after I restarted PC and open Toad, all my saved connections were missing. This is around the time when I noticed the SQL Editor no longer allow me to edit.

Please help.

Comment: No answer yet...new to TOAD and at least one can think it would be possible to edit queries and query a database for some data...???

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:
http://toad.10940.n7.nabble.com/Keyboard-problem-in-Toad-v-8-6-td6991.html

Apparently, there is a file plsqlkeys.bin created in some temp-folder that TOAD tries to use. Sometimes, apparently, it gets corrupt, and editing is no longer possible.

1. Close TOAD.
2. Search for file plsqlkeys.bin
3. Remove the file
4. Start TOAD - tada!

Cheers!